# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError bei importing maven Project to another one

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import

I have 2 Projects in Eclipse:
The first one is a maven project using google AdWords API dependencies and the second one is a dynamic web project. I have imported the first project by clicking on the second -> import -> Existing Maven Projects -> MyFirstProjectFolder -> Finish. It made a new pom.xml.

I've used a class from the first project in the second by importing it and running a method of it and i get an error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
I'm not a professional java programmer but as I understood the second project doesn't get the class but in my eclipse editor I have no errors or mistakes.

I hope I was precise enough. Thank you in advance.

```
package com.adwordsfeatures;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

import url_checker.*;


@Path("/hello")
public class ServerService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("first")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hi everyone";
    }
    @GET
    @Path("go")
    public String go(){
        runProgramMethod();
        return "<p1>Programm running</p1>";
    }
    private void runProgramMethod() {
        MainPauserMethod runner = new MainPauserMethod();

    }
}
```

this is the code in the second Project and the class i'm trying to use from the first project is the MainPauserMethod (i know it's a class it's just a test i'll change the name) and it's from the package url_checker.

Comment: Try to update maven dependencies.

Comment: thank you for your answer but could you be more precise please.

Comment: Right click on your project then maven and update project. Or in your project catalog run mvn clean install from command line